# Convert.ToBoolean("1") throws System.Format Exception in C#

Tags: c#

Why does

```
Convert.ToBoolean("1")
```

throw a `System.FormatException`?

How should I proceed with this conversion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx):

> [throws] FormatException [if] value is not equal to TrueString or FalseString.

`TrueString` is "True" and `FalseString` is "False".

If you want to detect whether a string is "1" or not, use this code:

```
bool foo = text == "1";
```

Comment: sir,I tried with this code and it works.Is there any better way to do this conversion. 

Boolean someBool=ddlSpeechRecognition.SelectedItem.Value == "1" ? true : false;

Comment: @Rohit: No need to use the conditional operator. Just do `Boolean someBool=ddlSpeechRecognition.SelectedItem.Value == "1";`

Comment: @Rohit: It's not a "conversion". You compare a string, ddlSpeechRecognition.SelectedItem.Value, to another one, "1". That comparison has a boolean value.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you want. Perhaps

```
var result = Convert.ToInt32(yourstirng) != 0
```

assuming any number but 0 is true. Otherwise a simple comparison would work.

```
var result = yourstirng == "1"
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter must be equal to either `Boolean.TrueString` or `Boolean.FalseString`. The values of these strings are "True" and "False", respectively. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx).

The string value "1" is obviously not equal to "True" or "False".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that youre giving a String here, not a number. It cant convert the String "1" to true, but the int 1.

`Convert.ToBoolean(1);`

should work.

Answer (score 1):

When converting to Boolean it is best to use **your own routine**, where you handle all cases.  .net Convert.ToBoolean isn't a practical routine, it is one of those function where you have to **explain** why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case someone searches... simply do this:

Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16("1")) works just fine. Not pretty, but needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an Extension Method on the string object. I used this technique in a case where I had to parse CSV files that had different strings that had to be converted to boolean values depending on their source and format.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ToBool(this string value,string trueValue)
    {
        if (value == trueValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be called like so...

```
MyProperty = CsvColumn[6].ToBool("1");
```

If you want, the truevalue parameter could be a string array if you needed to compare multiple values (like n/a, na, none) and you could add in false values if you want to further restrict it or use nullable types.