# Why does Convert.ToBoolean("0") fail?

Tags: c#

I know that trying to convert string "0" to boolean will fail, I also know how to fix this, thanks to Jon Skeets answers on other questions.

What I would like to know is WHY does C# not recognize "0" as a valid input for a boolean conversion, surely you could look at it like 0 = false, 1 = true, or even -1 = false and 0 = true, anyways, my logic tells me that it could be a valid input, so is there a very good reason why its not? My bet is old vb6 would be able to recognize the string input "0" as valid.

Comment: here is the correct way to convert for those of you interested - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606406/convert-toboolean1-throws-system-format-exception-in-c

Comment: You could also use : System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToBoolean(string), which accepts "0" and "1".

Comment: Be aware that `XmlConvert` requires "true" and "false" to be completely lowercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is because that is the way the method is defined. However, in C# `0` does not evaluate to `false`, so it would be surprising if "0" were to be converted to false using Convert.

Comment: very interesting, so a Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16("0")) would fail too?

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that it's because a C programmer coming over to a .NET language might be confused, since in C a straight cast of the character '0' would evaluate to "true", whereas the character '\0' would evaluate to "false".

(This is because the null character actually *is* byte full of zeroes, and the '0' character is a nonzero ASCII/Unicode/etc isn't.)

Comment: Anything to do with language purity maybe?

Comment: I think it's more about predictability and being conservative than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

a string with value always will return to true and even an empty string.

Comment: Why is this, can you please explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: If you really need to make that algorithm work, you can use the int.TryParse("0", out i); then convert that i to boolean

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straight forward, Convert.ToBoolean(String) calls Boolean.TryParse().  Which only accepts "True" or "False".  If you like to widen the options then you can, there are .NET languages that have a more flexible type system.  It is well supported by the .NET framework:

```
 bool b = (bool)Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean("0");
```

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: That is hardly a helpful comment now is it?

Comment: Then I would have said "**This** is hardly a helpful comment".  :)

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason as the following code will not compile.

```
bool value = 0;
//error CS0031: Constant value '0' cannot be converted to a 'bool'
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx 
According to above msdn link this method Converts the specified string representation of a logical value to its Boolean equivalent.

```
public static bool ToBoolean(
    string value
)
```

Parameters

value
Type: System.String
A string that contains the value of either [Boolean.TrueString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring.aspx) or [Boolean.FalseString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring.aspx). 
Return Value

Type: System.Boolean
true if value equals TrueString, or false if value equals FalseString or null.
Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you give `"0"` as a parameter it considers that as a string value. And string can't be converted to bool doesn't matter whether it is `0` or `1` .